# How to create different layouts in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Who can help me for my doubts regarding Ruby on Rails.Suppose i have 3 pages(i.e-home,about,contact us) which i want to create.Each page should have different different template.As we know in ROR we have one "`application.html.erb`" inside Layout directory.

I have the following code in `application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo Oditek</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all',
                                           'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
      </script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <li><%= link_to "Home",   '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Help",   '#' %></li>
            <li><%= link_to "Log in", '#' %></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`
```

The tag `<%= yield %>` renders the all pages inside `<div class="container"></div>`
But i need different different template for about and contact us pages.How can i create these.Please provide me some idea or reference link.

Answer (score 8):

You can add more layouts to folder views/layouts. Now you have only views/layouts/application.html.erb.

You can add `views/layouts/home.html.erb` or `views/layouts/dashboard.html.erb`.

To choose which layout to use you can define it in controller, for all actions, or just override layout for particular view.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController

  # all other actions will have application layout
  layout 'dashboard', :only => [:action_1, :action_2]

end
```

Comment: One thing to note - when you start using alternate layouts, you'll probably want to make a lot of each layout the same as in application.html.erb (eg the contents of `head`).  Put these shared sections in partials which each template can reference, so that the template file mostly has only the html which is unique to that template:  basically, Don't Repeat Yourself.

Answer (score 2):

In your controller:

```
def about
  @my_model = MyModel.where('whatever')
  render layout: 'about'
end
```

Then in layouts create a file called `about.html.erb`